# Fixed positioning breaks navigation menu

Tags: html, css, web

I have a navigation bar with sub menus ordered like:

nav > ul > li + div > ul > li > a

Each nav > ul > li has a div under it for a submenu that is hidden until
the user hovers over nav>ul>li. When the nav has no positioning this works,
but when I set position:fixed on nav, the submenus stop appearing. I've tried everything
I know to try and I have no idea why this is happening. It's not browser specific, the problem persists on chrome,safari and firefox.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Title</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navbar.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css"> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <nav> 
    <ul>     
            <li><a class="top" href="TODO">Blog </a> </li> 
            <div> 
                    <ul> 
                            <li><a href="TODO">Blog1</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="TODO">Blog2</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="TODO">Blog3</a></li> 

                    </ul> 
            </div> 
            <li><a href="TODO">Links </a></li> 
                    <div> 
                            <ul> 
                                    <li><a href="TODO">Link1</a></li> 
                                    <li><a href="TODO">Link2</a></li> 
                                    <li><a href="TODO">Link3</a></li> 
                            </ul> 
                    </div> 
            <li><a href="TODO">Projects</a> </li> 
            <div> 
                    <ul> 
                            <li><a href="TODO">Project1</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="TODO">Project2</a></li> 

                    </ul>
            </div>
            <li><a class="bottom" href="TODO">About</a> </li>
            <div></div>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <header>
            <p> My header </p>
    </header>
    <section>
            <p> My section </p>
    </section>
    <footer>
            <p> My footer </p>
    </footer>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #EBE8E4;
  color: #222;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue",     Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
}   
nav {
    position:fixed;
}   

nav,nav > ul > li + div ul > li > a { 
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  color: #888;
  text-decoration:none;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 22px 8px 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 165px; 
}   
nav > ul > li + div ul > li > a { 
    margin:0px;
    width:117px;
    border:0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0px;
}   
  nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }   

    nav ul li {
      display: block;
      list-style-type: none;
    }   


nav > ul > li > a { 
  color: #aaa;
  display: block;
  line-height: 56px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}   

  nav > ul > li:hover {
    background-color: rgb( 40, 44, 47 );
  }   

  nav > ul > li:hover > a { 
    color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
  }   

nav > ul > li + div {
  background-color: rgb( 40, 44, 47 );
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 165px;
  visibility: hidden;

}
nav > ul > li:hover + div,
    nav > ul > li + div:hover {
   display: block;
   margin-left:165px;
   margin-top:-56px;
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
   background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
   block-radius:4px;
 }

nav > ul > li + div > ul > li:hover {
    background-color: rgb(250,0,0);
    border: 0px;
    border-radius:4px;
}
nav > ul > li + div  ul > li:hover > a {
    background-color: rgb(40,44,47);
    color: rgb( 250 , 250 ,250);
}

nav > ul > li + div ul > li {
  display: block;
}

nav > ul > li + div ul > li > a {
  color: #aaa;
  background-color:#fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav > ul > li > div ul > li:hover > a {
  background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: Can you setup any kind of an working example, like JSFiddle or CodePen, so everybody can see more clearly what's going on?
Furthermore the W3C defines only `li` elements as children of `ul`, not `div`. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element So that might can cause positioning problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the `overflow:hidden` in the `nav,nav > ul > li + div ul > li > a` css rule. Remove `overflow:hidden` and it will work for you.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/2vjpkrzs/

CSS:

```
nav, nav > ul > li + div ul > li > a {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  color: #888;
  text-decoration:none;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 22px 8px 22px;
  width: 165px;
}
```